# What kind of list is this, and how do I read from it?

Tags: python, discord.py

As the title suggests, I have a very odd list. I would like to know how I could access its contents. Here is the list:
`[<Member id=703037947715 name='beck42' discriminator='4458' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=70183550138 name="not important" shard_id=None chunked=True member_count=69>>]` 
I am trying to read the Member ID, but cannot figure out how to get the output to not just be the entire list. Here is the code I have so far:

```
@commands.has_role("Admin")
async def addrole(ctx, roleID, member):
    members = ctx.message.mentions
    print(members[0:1])#only for debug purposes 
    memberID = await bot.fetch_user(user_id=members[0])
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(role_id=int(roleID))
    await members[0].add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please provide a [mcve] including properly formatted input, expected output, and code for what you've tried based on your own research. The sample you provided is not valid python code, and you haven't defined your specific issue

Comment: It looks like your list contains an instance of a `Member` object. Custom classes can define what their human readable string representation looks like so you can get something like that. `the_list[0]` should get it.

Comment: @tdelaney I tried that, this is the output of that

Comment: @Beck34 ... right, so *what's the problem*?

Comment: I cannot figure out how to read from it. The only output I am getting is the list @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: to get an item from a list by index, you use `my_list[index]`, so here `members[0:1]` you probably want `members[0]`... which you seem to already understand?

Comment: The output of that is just the entire list@juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: **No it isn't**. Please provide a [mcve]. Again, `my_list[index]` **does not return the entire list**, unless you happen to have the list referencing itself at that index.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga My mistake, it is outputting the name and discriminator instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) to get the model objects.

```
from discord import Role, Member

@commands.has_role("Admin")
async def addrole(ctx, role: Role, member: Member):
    await member.add_roles(role)
```